# Common content (logic core) in Git

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a kernel which includes the logic and some general functions to make my develops faster.

I am thinking about how include my logic core (kernel) in all my projects and if I want to update one day my kernel, do something like this:

```
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m "One commit with changes"

Changes of your project and your kernel repositories 
have been committed successfully!

$ git push myProject master
$ git push kernel v2.1
```

update my project and the changes of kernel in different repositories.

I have thought create a repository called: "kernel" and another one repository for each project. Also, for each project set a .gitignore file with the paths of the kernel directories and files.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) should be the thing you are looking for.

There is the [repo](https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/) tool that might come in handy for you. Not sure where the tool is at the moment because I have not used it in years, but it should be close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot Lyudmila!!
I'll try it, I don´t think I had troubles.

Comment: Be wary of submodules. Be very wary. Read, for instance [this blog](https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/).